# PC adjusted genetic association analysis?

Tags: pca, genetics

I was just wondering, when papers say "We adjusted the genotype for the first 3 principal components", are they using the eigenvectors, or the eigenvalues, from a Principal Component Analysis as cofactors in a genetic association analysis?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @fra! It means to adjust eigenvectors as covariates.

Comment: Thank you Randel, also for your reply! I was thinking more eigenvalues… good to know!